# Dynamic variable different for every Wordpress post: how to declare in loop?

Tags: variables, wordpress, dynamic-variables

I need a wordpress loop that for every post checks a meta numeric variable previously assigned to each of the taxonomies of the post and returns the sum of these meta variables.
To do so, I think I need a dynamic variable name for the total. I mean something like:

variablerelatedtopost = metataxonomy1 + metataxonomy2 + ... + metataxonomyn
echo variablerelatedtopost

How can I do that? Is it possible to generate a dynamic numeric variable via loop? and HOW can I refer to it in a general way, without adressing it with its name?
Thanks everyone! And sorry for possible English mistakes :P

EDIT: I just realized the code by Alex is not what I wanted. I need a variable which changes name at every post and which value is always = 0. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you not just add a counter to your loop like this?

```
//Total should start @ 0 before the loop
$total = 0;

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$amount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_meta_data_field', true);
$total = $total + $amount;
endwhile;

//echo total
echo $total;
```

Comment: I used your solution with a little change:

`while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$amount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_meta_data_field', true);
$total = $amount + $variablerelatedtotaxonomy;
echo $total;
endwhile;`

because I needed the total to be different for every post (every post counts just the taxonomy related variables of the post), but the principle works! thank you very much!

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake: I just realized the code is not what I wanted. I need a variable which changes name at every post and which value is always = 0, so this is not the right solution. I posted the answer by mistake checking it in a function with just one taxonomy-variable (it worked that way, with two variables obviously it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem: an array which increases its lenght at every cicle of the loop. I know it's simple but since I'm just a beginner it took me a while to think about it. I post the code here so maybe it can help someone (and if you find bugs or have improvements, please tell me)

```
//Before the loop, empty array
$totale = array();

// WP Loop
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$totale[] = 0;
$indice = (count($totale)) - 1;

// $termvariable was previously set up as a term meta value
if( has_term( 'numberofterm', 'nameoftaxonomy' ) ) {
$totale[$indice] = $termvariable + $totale[$indice];
}
```